# stop current thread until input is received from another window wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I want to stop other `Thread`s until the user provides input in this window... giving code that I have as such:

```
if (!File.Exists(@"DiscoveryConfig.bin"))
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((showRangeInputWindow)delegate()
    {
        new WinSubnetRangeInput().Show();
    }, null);
}
```

Lets say the following code do a `Ping` scan of network nodes but first it opens a window to take a range. But, how to stop scanning until input is received in this window...

Could I do this by getting thread ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user .ShowDialog()

if you window is named secondRibbonWindow then use

```
secondRibbonWindow.showDialog();
```